# No se muestra contenido de la App en React Native Aplication

Tags: typescript, react-native

Buenas estaba desarrollando una App muy sencilla en React Native, en la cual simplemente pretendía hacer una llamada a una API y recuperar la información en la pantalla principal.

Haciendo click en cada uno de los items se permite navegar una pantalla de detalles.

Creo haber implementado todo correctamente, incluido el navigation, aunque al iniciar la app, se muestra una pantalla en blanco.

Con respecto al código

HomeScreen.tsx

```
import {StackScreenProps} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import {RootStackParams} from '../navigation/Navigation';
import {useNews} from '../hooks/useNews';
import {HomeComponent} from '../components/HomeComponent';
import {title} from 'process';
import {New} from '../interfaces/newsInterface';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import useAxiosEffect from '../hooks/useAxiosEffects';
//TODO: Mostrar las noticias ordenadas por fecha,:
const data = useNews();

export const HomeScreen = () => {
  let [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const axiosEffect = useAxiosEffect(
    'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?domains=wsj.com',
    10000,
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, [axiosEffect]);
  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View>
        <ActivityIndicator color="red" size={100} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={data as unknown as readonly any[]}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id.toString() + index}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Detailscreen')}>
            <HomeComponent new={item} />
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        )}
        horizontal={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{marginTop: 10, height: 70}}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

HomeComponent.tsx

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ImageSourcePropType,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from 'react-native';
import {useNews} from '../hooks/useNews';
import {New} from '../interfaces/newsInterface';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

interface Props {
  new: New;
}

const navigation = useNavigation();

export const HomeComponent = ({new: New}: Props) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const {title, description, urlToImage} = useNews();

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View>
        <ActivityIndicator color="red" size={100} />
        {console.log('NOOOOO Cargoooooooooooooooooooooooo!')}
      </View>
    );
  }
  //TODO: Hacer un map para recoger
  //el mismo indice, que corresponda a cada noticia.
  return (
    <>
      <View style={{alignContent: 'center'}}>
        {title.map((data, i) => {
          <View key={i}>
            <Text>
              Title:
              {data}
            </Text>
          </View>;
        })}
        <br />

        {description.map((data, i) => {
          <View key={i}>
            <Text numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode="clip">
              Description:
              {data.toLowerCase}
            </Text>
          </View>;
        })}
        <br />
        <br />

        {urlToImage.map((data, i) => {
          <View key={i}>
            <Image
              source={data as ImageSourcePropType}
              style={styles.image}></Image>
          </View>;
        })}
        <br />
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DetailScreen')}>
            <Icon color="white" name="arrow-forward-outline" size={60} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
    borderRadius: 18,
  },
});
```

Navigation.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import {HomeScreen} from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import {DetailScreen} from '../screens/DetailScreen';

//TODO:
//En la pantalla detalle tiene que ir el título, la //descripción completa, la imagen de la noticia y //un botón “Ver en el navegador"
export type RootStackParams = {
  HomeScreen: typeof HomeScreen;
  DetailScreen: typeof DetailScreen;
};
const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParams>();

export const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="DetailScreen" component={DetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

No se si me esta pasando algo al llevar a pensas unos meses con React Native.

Si podéis ayudar muchas gracias de ante mano!